# Android: Pause/Resume Timer OR Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, timer

I have checked all SO answers about how to pause/resume timer, but can't find a  solution.

I have created a Timer task which counts the effort time for an employee and puts it inside a TextView to show.

Code below:

```
Timer T = new Timer();
    T.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String workingTime = "Your effort is "
                            + format.format(Double.valueOf(hr)) + ":"
                            + format.format(Double.valueOf(min)) + ":"
                            + format.format(Double.valueOf(sec))
                            + " till now for the day";
                    storeEffort.setText(workingTime);
                    sec++;
                    if (sec > 59) {
                        sec = 0;
                        min = min + 1;
                    }
                    if (min > 59) {
                        min = 0;
                        hr = hr + 1;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }, 1000, 1000);
```

where *storeEffort* is my TextView which shows the effort time which is stuck inside the running thread(main problem). I want to pause the effort timer with a button click and resume it when the same button clicked again.Is there any other way to do this kind of task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You solution might have a slight problem - you are using timer to count time intervals whereas there is no need to. You could use i.e. [`StopWatch`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/src-html/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html#line.76) to count elapsed time. So instead of adding seconds in a timer job you could just get elapsed time from this timer. To pause the timer you could call `stopWatch.stop()` and to start it, you could call `stopWatch.start()`.

It could look like this:

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();

void startThreadUpdateTimer(){}
    Timer T = new Timer();
    T.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String workingTime = "Your effort is " + sw.toString() + 
                         " till now for the day";                        
                }
            });
        }
    }, 1000, 1000);
}

public void pause(){
    if(stopwatch.isRunning()){
        stopwatch.stop();
    }
}

public void resume(){
    if(!stopwatch.isRunning()){
        stopwatch.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm what about periodic calls?

Comment: Periodic calls? I'm not sure I understand what this is. My suggestion seems being equivalent for what the OP is asking for.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable, long, long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) last two parameters provide the period in which the task will be executed - periodic calls

Comment: @BorisStrandjev I have updated the code, hope it's better now.

Comment: Then first i have to create the stopwatch class which link you have sent.. ..right

Comment: Yep, it might me missing on Android.

Comment: Gosh, you can live without any of these annotations. Here I've created a demo with a stopwatch: http://ideone.com/rKvdyw.

Comment: Ya.. its fine.Stopwatch is better that Timer and it works fine .Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Can you help me a little that how to continue the stopwatch after close application.

Comment: Thanks.this works fine.Now i am going to implement with a service which helps the timer to continue after closing.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** Solution if the timer needs to start from beginning every second time:

```
public class YourOuterClass extends Activity {
    private YourTimerTask mTimerTask;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Button button;
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mTimerTask != null && mTimerTask.isTaskActive()) {
                    mTimerTask.deactivateTimer();
                    mTimerTask = null;
                } else {
                    startTask();
                }

            }
        });
        ...
    }

   private class YourTimerTask extends TimerTask {
       private boolean mIsTimerActive;

       public YourTimer() {
           mIsTimerActive = true;
       }

       public void deactivateTimer() {
           mIsTimerActive = false;
       }

       public boolean isTaskActive() {
           return mIsTimerActive;
       }

       @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String workingTime = "Your effort is "
                            + format.format(Double.valueOf(hr)) + ":"
                            + format.format(Double.valueOf(min)) + ":"
                            + format.format(Double.valueOf(sec))
                            + " till now for the day";
                    if (!mIsTimerActive) {
                        cancel(); // will cancel this timer instance
                    }
                    sec++;
                    if (sec > 59) {
                        sec = 0;
                        min = min + 1;
                    }
                    if (min > 59) {
                        min = 0;
                        hr = hr + 1;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
   }
...
   private void startTask() {
      Timer T = new Timer();
      mTimerTask = new YourTimertask();
      T.scheduleAtFixedRate(mTimerTask, 1000, 1000);
   }
}
```

Comment: ..still i'm not able to pause the timer. when i click the button it pauses on the foreground only ,but still running in the background. And when again i click the button it continues with its current time not the pause one. any ideas

Comment: @RanjitPati Sure, just reset the value on every click of the button. However if you want to restart it from 0 I think there is better solution. I will be adding it in my answer.

Comment: Sorry Boris. You still not understand my problem. I want to pause and resume the time. the best example is multiple swipein/swipeout. From start swipeIn the counter starts, when you want to go out for sometime you have to swipeout and time pauses there. then time resumes when you come in and swipeIn again..

Comment: @RanjitPati see my edit, though now I am really not sure I understand the question. Should the timer really resume, or start all over? Should you support multiple instances?

Comment: i have two buttons. if you click first1 then the timer starts. when you click the 2nd one it pauses. Again the time resumes when you click the first one. your solution is fine but it works only on foreground. Because the time not stops in background. hope you understand..

Comment: @RanjitPati Now the latest update of my answer should work for you if we assume that `sec` is class variable.

Comment: ..your solution is also good and helped me to understand the problem and also solved some other bugs.Thanks ..+1